# Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to find a limit

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Find the limits $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+nx^2}$

This problem was given at the end of Lebesgue Integration Chapter. I assume I have to use use Lebesgue Convergence Theorem. In other words I have to find a function $g$ that dominates $f _n = \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+nx^2)}$ then prove that $f_n$ converge to a function $f$. If I prove this then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+nx^2} = \int_0^1 f$

Any help on finding $g$ and $f$? Thanks

Comment: $$g=f_1\qquad f=0$$

Comment: So if $g=f_1$, how do i prove that $|\frac{ln(1+x)}{1+nx^2}| <\frac{ln(1+x)}{1+x}$, Can you explain on this? And if f=0 the result will be 0, correct?

Comment: Kind of a weird problem. The integrand is bounded above by $x/(1+nx^2),$ whose integral can be done exactly.

Comment: Well... because $1+nx^2\geqslant1+x^2$ for every $n\geqslant1$ and because $\log(1+x)\geqslant0$, what else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb N^*$ and $x\in[0,1]$
$$\left|\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+nx^2}\right|\leq\frac{x}{1+nx^2}\leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}\in L^1(0,1)$$
Then you can use convergence dominated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with $\left|\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+nx^2}\right|\le\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+x^2}$ either.

Comment: Did I say that something was wrong ? :-)

Comment: @Surb Not at all.  Your answer is correct and a solid way forward.  So, well done!    I was only pointing out that we need not apply the inequality $\log (1+x)<x$ to arrive at the same conclusion.  I posted an answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Convergence towards zero is a trivial consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\log^2(1+x)\,dx = 2\left(1-\log(2)\right)^2, $$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(1+nx^2)^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1+n}+\frac{\arctan\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}\right).$$
It is also true that:
$$ 0\leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{1+n x^2}\,dx \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+n x^2}\,dx = \frac{\log(n+1)}{2n}.$$

Comment: Hammers and nails and all that...

Comment: @Did: ... and a bottle of rum?

Answer (score 0):

We have the simple inequality

$$1+nx^x\ge 1+x^2, n\ge 1 \tag 1$$

Thus, using $(1)$ reveals that

$$\left|\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+nx^2}\right|\le \frac{\log (1+x)}{1+x^2}$$

Since we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1+x)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\frac{\pi \log 2}{8}$$

then by the dominated convergence theorem

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+nx^2}\,dx&=\int_0^1\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{\log (1+x)}{1+nx^2}\right)\,dx\\\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

and we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can. If the answer was not useful to warrant an up vote, I am happy to delete.